# Puede compartirse carpetas utilizando la API Google Drive?

Tags: nodejs, api, google-drive

estoy construyendo un Add-in en el cual quiero visualizar algunas carpetas que tengo en Google Drive, estas carpetas contienen documentos +  carpetas y archivos .PDF etc.

Dentro de mi Add-in ya tengo el código embebido que me genera cuando hago publico a web una carpeta o documento, y ese funciona, cualquier cambio que yo le agregue a los documentos en Drive,  se reflejan en mi Add-in , pero lo que no he logrado es hacer que de una lista de carpetas pueda compartirse con otros usuarios desde mi Addin. 
Cabe aclarar que si bien las carpetas se copian con todo y sus hipervínculos, no quiero que me lleve a la pagina del drive ya que los usuarios no tienen cuentas de Google y por políticas de su empresa tienen limitados o bloqueados sitios web, como los es google Drive.

Existe dentro de la documentación de la API Google Drive algo que me permitiera, mostrar en mi aplicación las carpetas y estas a su vez poder compartirse.

Answer (score 0):

## Respuesta corta

Sí, es posible compartir carpetas

## Respuesta extendida

Google Drive maneja los archivos y carpetas de forma diferente a otras herramientas tales como FTP, Microsoft OneDrive, Dropbox, entre otros, por lo los programadores interesados en deberían valorar que tan habituados están a la forma de trabajar de las otras herramientas y de ser necesario dedicar tiempo a estudiar el modelo de Google Drive API así como las aplicaciones para usuario final de la plataforma Google Drive y las cuentas de Google.

En Google Drive API los archivos y carpetas son manejados con la clase [file](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files). Enfatizo,

> las carpetas se manejan con la clase **file**.

El acceso a archivos y carpetas se determina por listas de control de acceso (ACL por las siglas en inglés). Para más información, favor de leer las referencias.

## Referencias

- [About files and folders](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-files)
- [Permissions](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-permissions)